# smptlib.SMTP throws an error while using 'localhost',why does it happen?

Tags: python-3.x, email, localhost, smtplib

I was just trying to learn how to send emails using the email module and smtplib. This is what I'm getting.

```
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import smtplib
>>> from email.message import EmailMessage
>>> with open("file.txt") as fp:
...     msg = EmailMessage()
...     msg.set_content(fp.read())
... 
>>> msg['Subject'] = f'The contents of file'
>>> msg['From'] = "s*i*a*d*1*@gmail.com"
>>> msg['To'] = "s*i*a*k*9*@gmail.com"
>>> s = smtplib.STMP('localhost')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'STMP'
>>> s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I want to host it using localhost and it throws this error. Can anyone tell me how to solve it, please?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely no SMTP is running (acdcepting incoming SMTP connections) at localhost.

Local SMTP server is default on Unix/Linux  unlike on MS OSes.

AFAIR On Ubuntu local SMTP server is provided by default by postfix package. It may alternatively be provided by senndmail or exim packages (or a few more less popular).

Comment: so, what's the solution??

Comment: @SairajK Name OS you are using (Windows/Linux)

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Have you installed MTA/SMTP or SMTP server (package)?  AFAIR Ubuntu prefers postfix (other standard alternatives are  sendmail or exim).

Comment: oh! okay got it.